# How do I put this if-else statement from the while, in a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sum, integer

So, initially I did this if-else nested in a while loop to add all the squares of the odd numbers between to numbers. For example, if it the two numbers were 10 and 20, the sum of the squares of the odd numbers would be 1165 (11^2 + 13^2 + 15^2 ...). So, now I want to use a for loop instead of a while loop. I've seen other examples, but I can't implement with mine since it's only my second with working with C.

The following is the while loop and the print statement for the answer (I made "i" = firstNum, so firstNum wouldn't change in value, and firstNum and secondNum is just input from the user):

```
i = firstNum;
while (i <= secondNum) {
    // checks if number is odd or even
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sumOdds += i * i;
        i += 2;
    }
    else {
        ++i;
    }
}
printf("\n");
printf("Sum of the squares of odd integers between %d and %d = %d\n", firstNum, secondNum, sumOdds);
```

Comment: Why do you want a for loop? And what blocks you from writing one? What is the problem?

Comment: I have a feeling it's the play with the variable `i` that OP can't get his/her head wrapped around.

Comment: I just wanted a for loop since my instructor said to convert all our while loops in our previous assignment, and it was the if-else statements I couldn't get my head wrapped around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop can look for example the following way

```
for ( int i = firstNum + ( firstNum % 2 == 0 ); i <= secondNum; i += 2 )
{
   sumOdds += i * i;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    
    int firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter two numbers: " );
    scanf( "%d %d", &firstNum, &secondNum );
    
    if ( secondNum < firstNum )
    {
        int tmp = firstNum;
        firstNum = secondNum;
        secondNum = tmp;
    }
    
    long long int sumOdds = 0;
    
    for ( int i = firstNum + ( firstNum % 2 == 0 ); i <= secondNum; i += 2 )
    {
        sumOdds += ( long long int )i * i;
    }
    
    printf( "The sum of squares of odd numbers is %llu", sumOdds );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter two numbers: 10 20
The sum of squares of odd numbers is 1165
```

Some notes to the program. Firstly the variable `i` is used only within the for loop. So it should be declared in the minimum scope where it is used

```
for ( int i = firstNum + ( firstNum % 2 == 0 ); i <= secondNum; i += 2 )
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly to reduce the risk of overflow it is desirable to declare the variable  `sumOdds` at least as having the type `long long int`.

Comment: Nice reduction to notice that the OP's `else` would only be executed _once_ and should not be part of the loop (i.e. removing all conditionals from the loop).

Comment: This is just nice!

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful and insightful!

Comment: Also, since I'm pretty new to this could you just explain the `int i = firstNum + ( firstNum % 2 == 0 );`, as in how does that work? Does this add the number if the `firstNum` is even?

Comment: @osit0_solit0 The expression firstNum % 2 == 0 is equal to 1 if firstNum is an even number.   Otherwise it is equal to 0. So if firstNum is an even number then firstNum + ( firstNum % 2 == 0 ) will yield the first odd number after this even number, And you need to sum odd numbers,

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thinking, just wanted to make sure. This was super clutch, dude, now I don't need the if-else statement!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop without the increment.

```
for(i = firstNum; i <= secondNum;) {
    // checks if number is odd or even
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sumOdds += i * i;
        i += 2;
    }
    else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Gives you exactly the same behavior as your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with a `for` loop with `++i` as its terminal statement; then, you can dispense with the whole `else {...}` block and replace the `i += 2` (in the `if` block) with another `++i` (which, combined with the terminal increment, will have the same net effect as `i += 2`).

Like this:

```c
for (i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; ++i) {
    // checks if number is odd or even
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sumOdds += i * i;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the increment of the loop so you add the remaining value.

```
for (int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; i++) {
    // checks if number is odd or even
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sumOdds += i * i;
        i++;
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: What is the `int i = 0;` for (after having `i = firstNum;` ***before*** the loop)?